# Akeeba subscription additional Payment Gateway

Tags: joomla, components, payment-gateway

I would like to integrate SecurePay payment gateway in Akeeba subscription component in Joomla 2.5
I am familiar with ceating component and modules in Joomla 1.5

Please give some guidance to integrate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All payment methods are standard Joomla! plugins, belonging to the `akpayment` group. Look at the existing plugins to learn how they work. Then - provided with the necessary information about SecurePay's payment handling - you should be able to write your own plugin.

Comment: @ nibra : Thanks for your comment. I copied the "ccAvenue" folder and pasted as new folder "securepay" and make the chanes in all files (xml, php and language) in plugins\akpayment\ but the Payment Gateway name is not listed in Plugin Manager list for Akeeba subscription. Please let me know how can I list the new plugin in Plugin manager to enable / disable and configure it. Please suggest.

Comment: Did you activate the plugin? Maybe you have to 'discover' it first.